# Echo a different value depending on a variable value

Tags: php

I have 2 variables in phtml and want to make them a link.

```
<?php
    $_reviewCount = $_ratingSummary->getReviewsCount(); 
    $_reviewUrl=$_product->getRequestPath().'#reviews';  

<!--Here if review count is 1 i want to show as "Review" else "Reviews" --> 

 <?php echo $_reviewCount ?>
<?php echo  "<a href='".$_reviewUrl."'>Review</a>" ?>
<?php ($_reviewCount == 1 ) ? __('Review') : __('Reviews') ?>
```

But the above shows only keyword 'review' in lowercase .

Comment: And what does `__` do?

Comment: its just a text to display based on condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rewrite your code to first define the singular or plural form and then echo it:

```
<?php 
    if($reviewCount==1){$text='Review';}else{$text='Reviews';}    
    echo  "<a href=\"$_reviewUrl\">$_reviewCount $text</a>";
?>
```

BTW i'd change the if condition to >1 because your code echoes Reviews if the count of reviews is 0.

```
<?php 
    if($_reviewCount>1){$text='Reviews';}else{$text='Review';}    
    echo  "<a href=\"$_reviewUrl\">$_reviewCount $text</a>"; 
?>
```

Comment: I dont want review keyword to be echoed if count =0 and also want to make the count value also to be included in a link and make keyword review as Review

Comment: actually this is exactly what the first version of the code does. What do you mean with _"count value also to be included in a link"_?

Comment: ok i got it, i mean like this: echo  "<a href=\"$_reviewUrl\">$_reviewCount $text</a>" and removing the echo $_reviewCount;

Comment: that was a part of your code I left untouched since I don't know what it was there for. Editing my answer